# Unterschied zwischen allozieren und allokieren

Tags: difference, technical-terminology

In der Wikipedia bin ich in einem Eintrag zum Thema *Speicherverwaltung in Computern* auf den Begriff „allozieren“ gestoßen.

Ein Computerprogramm muss im Hauptspeicher (RAM) für jede Art von Daten  Speicherplatz reservieren. Dabei erhält ein Datensatz eine eindeutige Adresse. Dies wird auch als *Allokation* bezeichnet. Im Englischen heißt *to allocate something* soviel wie „etwas zuzuordnen“ (hier: Den Daten einen Speicherplatz).

Mir ist daher auch das Wort „allokieren“ bekannt, auch da es sich sehr einfach ableiten lässt.

Ein Blick ins Wiktionary liefert für beide Begriffe eine ähnliche Beschreibung. Aber wo liegt genau der Unterschied?

[Definition für „allokieren“ im Wiktionary](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/allokieren)

[Definition für „allozieren“ im Wiktionary](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/allozieren)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Es gibt keinen Bedeutungsunterschied in Bezug auf die Speicherverwaltung. Lateinisch "c" kann als "k" oder "z" eingedeutscht werden, je nachdem, welche Aussprache man bevorzugt.

Meinem Sprachverständnis nach ist "allokieren" die ältere Form; ich würde "allozieren" nur im Zusammenhang mit Informatik verwenden. Man kann das Problem auch umgehen, indem man nur das Substantiv "Allokation" oder deutsche Ausdrücke wie "Speicherplatz reservieren" benutzt. :-)

Comment: Die Anpassung des Wortes bei der Übernahme aus einer Anderen Sprache macht Sinn. Es müssen nicht alle Begriffe mit einem "z" oder "k" deutsch klingen. Jedoch ist es interessant zu sehen, dass beide Varianten gebräuchlich sind.

Außerhalb der Informatik würde ich diese Begriffe auch selten verwenden. Professoren haben nun mal ihre bevorzugten Termini.

Answer (score 2):

Ich persönlich würde "allozieren" verwenden, da im Lateinischen ein "c" wie ein "z" ausgesprochen wird, sofern danach ein "e" oder ein "i" steht; andernfalls wird es wie ein "k" ausgesprochen. Insofern macht auch die Aussprache "Allokation" Sinn - diesen Sachverhalt kann man auch bei dem Nomen "Provokation" und dem zugehörigen Verb "provozieren" beobachten. Da "allozieren" jedoch nicht Teil des alltäglichen Sprachgebrauchs ist, ist es verständlich, dass der Normalbürger von diesem Nomen direkt das Verb "allokieren" ableitet; korrekter ist aber - zumindest meiner Ansicht nach - "allozieren".

Comment: Welche [Aussprache des Lateinischen](https://de.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deutsche_Aussprache_des_Lateinischen) und welche Normalbürger meinst Du?

Comment: Ich zitiere aus deinem verlinkten Artikel: "<c> wird vor <a>, <o> (außer in den Verbindungen <ae> und <oe>) und <u> wie ein deutsches <k> [k] und vor <ae>, <e>, <i>, <oe> und <y> wie ein deutsches <z> [ts] ausgesprochen."

Comment: Also die dort beschrieben Traditionsaussprache, keine der anderen? Warum diese?